# Apache Camel: manage several quartz in one route?

Tags: apache-camel

I have many quartz to schedule tasks like (ping, Email, etc.). Is it possible to manage many quartzes in one route in Apache Camel or I have to create route for every quarz?

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route route9 because of Multiple consumers for the same endpoint is not allowed: quartz://myTimer?cron=0+0/1+*+*+*+?+*
```

**Code:**

```
@Component
public class TimingRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimingRoute.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // Every 3 minutes: 0+0/3+*+*+*+?+*
        // Every 10 seconds: 0/10+*+*+*+*+?+*
        from("quartz://myTimer?cron=0+0/1+*+*+*+?+*") //
                .setBody().simple("Current time is " + LocalDateTime.now()) //
                .log("${body}").to("direct:processPollingEmail");

        from("quartz://myTimer?cron=0+0/1+*+*+*+?+*") //
                .setBody().simple("Current time is " + LocalDateTime.now()) //
                .log("${body}").to("direct:processPing");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did there already is "create route for every quartz".
I believe the only reason why you're getting this error is that you gave the same ID to both your quartz endpoints. Try naming them "myTimer" and "myTimer2" (or anything more meaningful like "emailTimer" and "pingTimer") and you should be fine.